# Multiple Select Unselect Checkbox using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Here is my code for select unselect checkbox using Jquery:

```
<input id="demo_box_0" class="checkAll css-checkbox chk_box" type="checkbox" onclick="selectAll(this)" title="Select All"/>
```

other checkbox are :

```
<input id=\"demo_box_".$row->CompanyID."\" class=\"css-checkbox csscheck\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"".trim($row->CompanyID)."\"  />
```

As i have lengthy class name i am not getting expecting result

Here is my script :

```
$('.checkAll css-checkbox chk_box').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('div input').attr('checked', true);
    } else {
        $('div input').attr('checked', false);
    }
});
```

What is the mistake i am doing and how can i fix this ?

Update :

I even tried this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#demo_box_0").click(function(){
        //alert("just for check");
        if(this.checked){
            $('.checkAll css-checkbox chk_box').each(function(){
                this.checked = true;
            })
        }else{
            $('.checkAll css-checkbox chk_box').each(function(){
                this.checked = false;
            })
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector is wrong, it should be:

```
$('.checkAll.css-checkbox.chk_box');
```

The above selector selects all the elements that have those 3 classNames. if you want it to just select the checkboxes that have those classNames you can also add the element type to the selector:

```
$('input[type=checkbox].checkAll.css-checkbox.chk_box');
```

Also for modifying properties you should use the `prop` method:

```
$('.checkAll.css-checkbox.chk_box').on('change', function() {
    $('div input').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Comment: But this is the class name for other checkbox , css-checkbox csscheck, wil that work ?

Comment: Should i remove the onclick function on checkbox ?

Comment: The above selector selects the elements that have those 3 classNames, it works just like css selectors. There is no need to specify all the classNames of the elements for selecting them; however, if there is a need for this, you can use it. You are using jQuery, preferably you shouldn't use event-related attributes.

Comment: But in console i got Uncaught ReferenceError: selectAll is not defined : onclick

Comment: @BizDev You can simply remove the `onclick` attribute, it has no effect on the above snippet.

Comment: And in another few pages i just noted it is already used -  $('input.csscheck:checkbox:checked').each(function() { - So $('input[type=checkbox].checkAll.css-checkbox.chk_box').on('change', function() { is not working, Is there any way to overcome it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64996/discussion-between-biz-dev-and-vohuman).